# Can we play video games during sabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat, electricity

I am not Jewish, but sort of try to emulate some parts of it to see if it does me any good.
Well, not doing anything for 1 day is too boring. Actually what else can we do anyway during sabbath beside sleeping? The game is diablo 3. Basically we "work" on gaining level trading items, etc. But hey it's a game. It's not like I am programming.
What would a Jew in my position do?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/is-it-a-discouraged-or-an-unacceptable-practice-for-a-gentile-to-keep-the-sabbat?lq=1

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7625/759

Comment: It's hard to spend the Sabbath alone, it is good to spend it together with friends and family. But there are lots of things you can do on this day. As one of the answers below says, 'work' is defined in a very particular way, based on certain types of actions. It's kind of about rest vs. work, but it's also about rest vs. *creative work*... that is, rest from certain kinds of creative work helps Jews to remember the fact that God a) created the world, and b) has given us our creative abilities as a gift that isn't inherent to us. (Cont...)

Comment: (Cont...) Anyway, if you are just emulating the Sabbath to see if it does you good, then you should not do it in the exact same way as Jews do because it's actually a special covenant symbol between Israel and God that other nations shouldn't copy. (Of course everyone from any nation is free to join the covenant and become Jewish, though, and then they can keep it!) But for your purposes, you may be better off formulating your own way of having a restful day... e.g. not doing any work that you feel time pressure to do, or that is like your 'weekday' work, or however you'd like to define it :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately video games are out on Shabbos, as we are [not permitted to manipulate electricity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12572/why-cant-electricity-be-manipulated-on-shabbat). "Working" on Shabbos is not defined by what we achieve, but rather what is defined in the Shulchan Aruch (Jewish Code of Law) as "work". (For example, the Talmud states that one can carry heavy loads around the house all day and not desecrate Shabbos, but carrying a small object to a different domain is forbidden.) An overview of the [basic laws of Shabbos can be found here](http://beta.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/95907/jewish/The-Shabbat-Laws.htm). Jews typically spend Shabbos in synagogue praying, spending time with the family and learning Torah.

Comment: So can't ask questions in judaism stack exchange either during sabbath because that means typing on keyboard? I asked this 6 pm on Indonesia time. Are you still in "sabbath" over there?

Comment: What about if the computer is always on?

Comment: @JimThio That's correct; notice how quite this site is on Saturday. Even if the computer is on it would still be a problem. I am in Australia so Shabbos finished for me a couple hours ago.

Comment: So 6pm Friday to 6pm Saturday. That's the correct timing right?

Comment: Acutually carrying heavy loads one can be Oiver on Uvdah DeChol

Comment: @JimThio Shabbat from sunset to nightfall so there is no set time, it changes every week.

Comment: @JimThio No problem to leave computer on, as long as no act is performed on the Sabbath itself (minor generalization but mostly true).

Comment: And going on walks, eating, and playing board games.

Answer (score 1):

the talmud says that Shabbat is given for the study of torah.if one does not learn torah, then indeed there is very little to do. furthermore, a nonjew is NOT allowed to keep shabbat by refraining from work. I think it's best to focus on doing your mitzvot properly, i.e. the 7 laws of bnei noach

Comment: I *think* "what else can we do anyway during sabbath beside sleeping?" was rhetorical, with the real question in the title.

Comment: The question asked "What would a Jew in my position do" Not "should a non-Jew keep the Sabbath" or should a non-Jew learn Torah.

Comment: `the talmud says that Shabbat is given for the study of torah` Where?

Comment: @mevaqesh רבי ברכיה בשם רבי חייא בר בא לא ניתנו שבתות וימים טובים אלא לעסוק בהן בדברי תורה.
http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2115.htm