# Shabbos activities for kids

Tags: halacha, shabbat, oneg-shabbat

We have three children aged 11 (boy), 4 (girl) 2 (boy).  We started keeping Shabbos a while ago and we realise that it gets hard for the kids at some point. I was wondering if you could suggest allowed  activities we could introduce.

We currently have

- Go out for walks
- Board games
- Read books
- Tell stories
- Ask questions about the Parsha
- Sing

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related (adults, not kids, but same problem and there may be overlap): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7625/472

Answer (score 6):

[Aish](http://www.aish.com/sh/f/Shabbat_Fun_for_Kids.html) has a long list of suggestions.

My favorites are for the kids to be involved with setting the table, preparing dishes prior to Shabbos and then bringing it to the table. Cutting vegetables, etc. Serving special Shabbos treats. Keep the humor rolling. Showing off school projects.

My kids play jumprope, and with hula hoops. They also often dress up with a box of costumes we have. They also make plays and shows. One of their favorites is looking at all the family pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i really appreciate it. We just had a good shabbos today. We went for a walk and read some books. I think the kids enjoyed today.

Answer (score 4):

The things you list. Also, besides board games are other games (card, word, ball, etc. Just be sure to follow the Sabbath rules, which restrict certain game-related activities). Also, Torah study.

Answer (score 2):

I jump rope with my kids on Shabbos. We also play frisbee in the park. (Our city is enclosed.)
They also enjoy role-playing games a.k.a. imagination games.