# Is there a way to minimize soreness or getting a lip blister from blowing the shofar?

Tags: medicine, how-to, shofar

Each year after I blow the shofar on Rosh Hashannah, the area on my lip at the right corner of my mouth where the shofar had rested gets very sore and sometimes I get a small blister which is a bit painful.

I don't know if I'm the only one that has this problem. Is there anyone than can suggest any techniques that would minimize the chances of getting this problem?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @mevaqesh yes. It's a question about ["general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism"](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @msh210 This hinges on the interpretation of "directly". I always thought that meant things like "what does Judaism hold about evolution" or "which kinds of electrical appliances have the following quality that makes them permissible on Shabbos. As opposes to question which result from Jewish observance, but do not relate to it directly, such as "I always get bored on Shabbos without melacha. What are some ways to entertain myself without melacha". Such a question _stems_ from a Jewish act (Shabbos), but directly asks about entertainment.

Comment: @mevaqesh re your comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7625 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34554 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44171

Answer (score 4):

I have to tell you, I am part of a large corps of shofar blowers, and I've never heard of anyone getting a painful blister. I have to think there must be something wrong with your shofar. Perhaps there is a narrow corner of the mouthpiece that pinches your lip, or (I hope not) an actual crack in the mouthpiece.

My recommendation is to borrow or otherwise obtain a different shofar for Yom Tov this year, and see if you can avoid the problem in this way. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Don't push the Shofar against your mouth so hard; which you're likely doing to block air from escaping. Instead, you can use your fingers to seal any spaces. I like to use my index and middle fingers, so the shofar is where "the fingers meet" (like how some people hold cigarettes, except closer to the base of the fingers.)

If you're not pressing the Shofar to your mouth, then look at the Shofar. The edge might be rough, or slightly cracked. Try using a different Shofar.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving shofar to different locations on your mouth. The authorities disagree about the correct side of the mouth for blowing shofar, and even disagree on whether the side matters. If blowing from the right side is part of your minhag, keep it on the right but just move the shofar slightly away from the corner of your lips.